# Why is the local variable within the recursive loop overidden? Recursive loops inside For loops for Java

Tags: java, recursion, combinations

I am writing a program that takes a number `n` and returns all the possible combinations to divide the group up into pairs.

To do this, I use a recursive method which begins with an ArrayList numbered 1 to `n`. Then I choose the first number and match it with another number, removing both. I pair the first number with every other number using a `For` loop and then I recall the method at the end. Thus, it will perform the same process except for `n-2` since I removed the paired numbers (storing them so they're not lost).

I found that this worked initially, but once it reached the base case the first time, the local variable that stores the ArrayList of numbers stayed at a null List when my program moved down the method-call stack to other recursive calls.

The ArrayList I am referring to is called 'numbers.' The recursive method is `createPair`. I attached my code below:

```
    public static void Combinations(int n){
    //store possible numbers that can be chosen
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(n);

    //store combinations and pairs
    ArrayList<int[]> pairs = new ArrayList<>();

    //returns it in the proper form
    //int[] value = new int[n];

    //reset number
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        numbers.add(i);
    }

    //do combinations
    //n-1, n-3, ... 1 (increments of two)
    createPair(pairs, numbers, n);
}

public static void createPair(ArrayList<int[]> pairs, ArrayList<Integer> numbers, int n){
    int length = numbers.size();

    //base case
    if(length == 0){
        int[] value = convertPair(pairs, n);
        List1.add(value);
        return;
    }

    int[] pair = new int[2];
    pair[0] = numbers.get(0);
    numbers.remove(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        pair[1] = numbers.get(i);
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers1 = numbers;
        numbers1.remove(i);
        pairs.add(pair);
        createPair(pairs, numbers1, n);
    }
}

//convert to one array value form
public static int[] convertPair(ArrayList<int[]> pairs, int n){
    int[] value = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n/2; i++){
        int index = pairs.get(i)[1]-1;
        int index2 = pairs.get(i)[0]-1;

        value[index] = pairs.get(i)[1];
        value[index2] = pairs.get(i)[0];
    }
    return value;
}
```

Also, the error message I get when it runs(for `n` = 8) is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
    at wormhole.createPair(wormhole.java:294)
    at wormhole.createPair(wormhole.java:300)
    at wormhole.createPair(wormhole.java:300)
    at wormhole.createPair(wormhole.java:300)
    at wormhole.Combinations(wormhole.java:277)
    at wormhole.main(wormhole.java:169)`
```

Answer (score 1):

After taking another look at my code, I was able to figure out the problem. I was removing numbers from the `numbers` ArrayList, so when the next recursion call ran, the ArrayList was already empty. To fix this, I created a temporary variable.